# How to accessing WCF APIs in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

i created an WCF API in my silverlight web project using Silverlight enabled WCF Services with name API.

I added operation contract logic in this :

```
[OperationContract]
 public int AddNums(int a, int b)
 {
    return (a + b);
 }
```

Now i added a Service Reference named "APIRef" in SilverLight Client project.

Now i know one way to access it using http://localhost:2250/API.svc
and it show some information regarding the API etc

But i want that a remote device can access the **AddNums(a,b)** method

How can i access this....please give guide

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a stub class on client side after adding the service reference.
You need to include it and call the method e.g.

```
APIRefClient.AddNums(x,y);
```

The important thing is, to take the ***Client class

Comment: Hi can you give me some guidence about creating stub class. Actually i am not able to resolve the issue

Comment: you just rightclick on the project in your visual studio and choose "Add Service Reference" - then you paste in the url with trailing ?wsdl click go - choose the service - give it a name and your ready to go...

Comment: take a look at: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/wcf/a1647f10-9aa4-4b0c-bbd9-dfa51a9fab8e/adding-wcf-service-references.aspx